# How does "std::cout << std::endl;" compile?

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution, iomanip

Most [IO stream manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) are regular functions with the following signature:

```
std::ios_base& func( std::ios_base& str );
```

However some manipulators (including the most frequently used ones - [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) and [`std::flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush)) are templates of the following form:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& func(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os);
```

Then, how does the compilation of `std::cout << std::endl;` succeed given that the following example fails:

```
$ cat main.cpp 
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto myendl = std::endl;
    std::cout << myendl;
}

$ g++ -std=c++11    main.cpp   -o main
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:5:24: error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘std::endl’
     auto myendl = std::endl;
                        ^
```

It is clear that the context (in `std::cout << std::endl;`) helps the compiler to disambiguate the reference to `std::endl`. But what are the rules that govern that procedure? It looks like a real challenge for overloading resolution, which has to answer two questions at once:

1. Which specialization of `std::endl<CharT, Traits>()` does `std::endl` refer to?
2. Which function does the `operator<<` refer to?

Template argument deduction (1) should happen before overload resolution (2), but it seems that (at least some part of) (2) is required to be performed in order for (1) to succeed.

---

Somewhat related but no-way duplicate questions are:

- [Does std::endl work with both cout and wcout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659798/does-stdendl-work-with-both-cout-and-wcout)
- [Why does endl(std::cout) compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295065/why-does-endlstdcout-compile)
- [How does std::flush work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105650/how-does-stdflush-work)

None of those questions and neither answers to them address the workings of template argument deduction that should precede overload resolution but must be helped by the latter.

---

**Follow-up question:** [How does overload resolution work when an argument is an overloaded function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343663/how-does-overload-resolution-work-when-an-argument-is-an-overloaded-function)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This question is not a duplicate. It's not even that Dietmar Kühl's answer contains information requested in my very different question (it only states that *"The compiler deduces the template arguments automatically"* while I am curious how that deduction works).

Comment: _@Leon_ Can you make up your arguments into your question why you think it's not clearly explained in Dietmar's or the other answers there please? I'd consider to reopen your question maybe.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I already added those arguments in my edit (before the question was closed).

Comment: Well, start with a [MCVE] when asking.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5dd253353203104e

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So what does your copy-paste of my example prove?

Comment: What's not answered in the dupe in particular?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This question is about C++ rules that govern overload resolution in what appear to be a quite intricate  (though very frequently used) situation. The answers in the dupe don't at all address how template argument deduction works in the context of such an overloading resolution.

Comment: Clarify that in your question then, rather than complaining in comments. It costs me just one click to reopen your question if you're willing to make the effforts.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Done.

Comment: OK, I'll let it go now. Not completely convinced but you shave shown more efforts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `operator<<` in question is a *member* of `std::basic_ostream`:

```
namespace std {
    template <class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT> >
    class basic_ostream {
    public:
        basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(
          basic_ostream<charT,traits>& (*pf)(basic_ostream<charT,traits>&));
        // ...
    };
}
```

Since the call is to `std::cout << std::endl`, or equivalently `std::cout.operator<<(std::endl)`, we already know the exact instantiation of `basic_ostream`: `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>`, aka `std::ostream`.  So the member function of `cout` looks like

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>& (*pf)
    (std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>&));
```

This member function is not a function template, just an ordinary member function.  So the question remaining, is can it be called with the name `std::endl` as an argument?  Yes, initializing the function argument is equivalent to a variable initialization, as though we had written

```
std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>& (*pf)
    (std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>&) = std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer provided hints that helped me better understand overload resolution in this case. I have posted a more abstract question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343663/how-does-overload-resolution-work-when-an-argument-is-an-overloaded-function

Answer (score 6):

Given a statement expression of the form

```
 std::cout << std::endl;
```

The compiler has information about the type of `std::cout` - which is a specialisation of the templated `std::basic_ostream` which looks something like (omitting the containing `namespace std`).

```
template <class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT> >
    class basic_ostream
{
    public:
        basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(
            basic_ostream<charT,traits>& (*pf)(basic_ostream<charT,traits>&));

        // other members ....
};
```

Since the compiler has information about the type of `std::cout` it knows what `charT` and `traits` are to specialise the preceeding template.

The above causes `std::endl` in the expression `std::cout << std::endl` to match to the specific `std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& endl( std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>&)`.

The reason type deduction doesn't work in

```
 auto myendl = std::endl;
```

is because `std::endl` is a templated function, and this declaration provides no information to specialise that template (i.e. picking what `charT` or `traits` are).   If it can't specialise the templated `std::endl`, it can't infer that function's return type, so the type deduction fails.

Answer (score 5):

Because `basic_ostream` has a templated overload of `operator<<` that expects just such a function pointer:

```
basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(basic_ios<charT, traits>& (*pf)(basic_ios<charT, traits>&));
```

Comment: And how does overloading resolution work in that case (see updated question)?

Answer (score -3):

You need to put << before the endl. It is a member of ofstream:

```
namespace std {
template <class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT> >
class basic_ostream {
public:
    basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(
      basic_ostream<charT,traits>& (*pf)(basic_ostream<charT,traits>&));
    // ...
};

}
```

endl works like a "/n" to skip the line, so you need a cout line to skip