# How does template argument deduction work when an overloaded function is involved as an argument?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overload-resolution, template-argument-deduction

This is the *more sophisticated question* mentioned in [How does overload resolution work when an argument is an overloaded function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343663/how-does-overload-resolution-work-when-an-argument-is-an-overloaded-function)

Below code [compiles without any problem](https://godbolt.org/g/3wWmJK):

```
void foo() {}
void foo(int) {}
void foo(double) {}
void foo(int, double) {}

// Uncommenting below line break compilation
//template<class T> void foo(T) {}

template<class X, class Y> void bar(void (*f)(X, Y))
{
    f(X(), Y());
}

int main()
{
    bar(foo);
}
```

It doesn't appear a challenging task for template argument deduction - there is only one function `foo()` that accepts two arguments. However, uncommenting the template overload of `foo()` (which still has just a single parameter) breaks compilation for no obvious reason. Compilation fails both with gcc 5.x/6.x and clang 3.9.

Can it be explained by the rules of overload resolution/template argument deduction or it should be qualified as a defect in those compilers?

Comment: This is explained by section 13.3 of the C++ Standard ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As noted in the answer to your linked question:

> `[temp.deduct.call]/6:`When `P` is a function type, pointer to function type, or pointer to member function type:
>
> — If the argument is an overload set containing one or more function templates, the parameter is treated
>   as a non-deduced context.

Since the overload set contains a function template, the parameter is treated as a non-deduced context. This causes template argument deduction to fail:

> `[temp.deduct.type]/4:` [...]If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced
>   contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.

And this failed deduction gives you your error. Note that if you explicitly specify the arguments, the code compiles successfully:

```
bar<int,double>(foo);
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d361ed80478a293)