# Is it possible to invoke a variadic template function without explicit specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17

I was trying to write a function to forward arguments for a variadic template function, similar to `std::invoke`. Here is the code:

```
#include <functional>

template<class... Args>
void f(Args&&... args) { }

template<template<class...> class F, class... Args>
void invoke(F<Args...> f, Args&&... args) {
    f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    invoke(f, 1, 2, 3);
    std::invoke(f, 1, 2, 3);
}
```

However, both my `invoke` and `std::invoke` fails to compile.
g++ complains that it couldn't deduce template parameter `template<class ...> class F`. So is it possible to invoke a variadic template function without explicit template specialization?

Comment: a variation about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356990/how-does-template-argument-deduction-work-when-an-overloaded-function-is-involve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that a function template represents a *family* of functions. When you, say, pass it to a function it needs to resolve to a certain *specialization* of the template. I understand what you're trying to do with the parameter of your custom `invoke` (capture the function template as a template) but sadly this will work only with class templates, never function templates.

You'd need another level of indirection. Namely, passing a functor or lambda that forwards the arguments to `f`:

```
invoke([](auto&&... xs) { f(decltype(xs)(xs)...); }, 1, 2, 3);
```

The difference is that now the argument is a class non-template so it can be deduced by your `invoke`.

With this change comes the additional requirement that you change your function to fully deduce the first parameter:

```
template<class F, class... Args>
void invoke(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
  f(forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Is `decltype(xs)` necessary? It works just fine when I removed it.

Comment: @debug18 That's to do forwarding. You could also spell it `std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)` or `static_cast<decltype(xs)&&>(xs)`, depending on preference.

Answer (score 2):

If function is wrapped inside of template class then you should be able to pass this template class as template template parameter:

```
#include <functional>

template<class... Args> struct Wrap
{
    static void f(Args&&... args) { }
};

template<template<class...> class F, class... Args>
void invoke(Args&&... args) {
    Wrap<Args...>::f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    invoke<Wrap>(1, 2, 3);
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DbsqfM7TkKASWqte)